# Alternative for "msg" command in .bat file for Windows 10 (64 bit)

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, 64-bit

I wrote a small timer-script as a .bat-file, which reminds me (16 times) every 30 minutes (1800 sec) in a pop-up messagebox to "Move!". The script works fine on Windows 7 (32 bit) Systems, but it seems that the "msg" command can´t be used or is not existent for 64-bit Systems. Is there any alternative to this command or way to replace that command easily?

```
set TIMER=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16)
set USERS=(%username%)
set MESSAGE=Move!

for %%i in %TIMER% do call :doit

:doit

for %%i in %USERS% do msg %%i %MESSAGE% 

timeout /t 1800 /nobreak
goto:eof
```

Comment: The command exists also on the 64-bit version of both Windows 7 and Windows 10. Do you have a Home edition or something, which might lack the `msg` command?

Comment: You may simplify your code this way: `for /L %%i in (1,1,16) do ( (for %%m in (%USERS%) do msg %%m %MESSAGE%) & timeout /t 1800 /nobreak)` You may split the code in several lines, if you wish...

Comment: (On Windows 10) I had a similar issue trying to run msg from a .bat file through visual studio (runs fine when clicking on it but not through VS), the issue was the msg.exe is contained within the C:\Windows\System32 folder and even supplying the full address of the .exe does not help as windows re-routes to the system folder when running it from 64 bit application. solution copy the msg.exe to the system folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary VBS script, run it then delete it.

[See Example MessageBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ5jD.png)

At the bottom of your program include:

```
exit /b
:msg
set tempPath=%temp%\msgbox.vbs
echo msgbox "%message%" > %tempPath% && %tempPath% && del %tempPath%
goto:eof
```

You can then use it through your script like so:

```
set message=Hello World
call:msg
```

So in your case:

```
set TIMER=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16)
set USERS=(%username%)
set MESSAGE=Move!

for %%i in %TIMER% do call :doit

:doit

set message=%MESSAGE%
call:msg

timeout /t 1800 /nobreak
goto:eof


exit /b
:msg
set tempPath=%temp%\msgbox.vbs
echo msgbox "%message%" > %tempPath% && %tempPath% && del %tempPath%
goto:eof
```

Comment: now i tried this solution, but it doesn´t work like this. the console window opens and Closes instantly without showing the messagebox.

Comment: I was too aggressive with those '&&': always test your code. Should be fixed now.

Comment: This is great man! It works now!

( PS: Do you even know how to change the message box size?)